# Python iloc gives out of bound indexer error

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv
with open('C:\PhD\Images\FD19\\count_post_1-2.csv') as csv_file:
 df1=pd.read_csv(csv_file, delimiter=',')

name=[] 
means=[0]*(len(df1))

key=df1['id']
key2=[]
mean=[]
tot=df1['count']-df1['spurious']+df1['undet']
df1['tot']=tot
df1['mean']=means

for i in range (0,len(df1)):
 k=key[i][:-1]

 key2.append(k)

key3=list(dict.fromkeys(key2))


 for m in key3:


        if str(m)+str(1)==df1.iloc[i,1] and str(m)+str(2)==df1.iloc[(i+1),1] and str(m)+str(3)==df1.iloc[(i+2),1] :

         av=((df1.iloc[i,5]+df1.iloc[i+1,5]+df1.iloc[i+2,5])/3) 
        # print(str(m)+str(1),df1.iloc[i,1])
         # print(av)
         # df1.iloc[i+2,6]=av
```

The code does not work for this loop but works for the next two even though they are similar

```
              elif str(m)+str(1)==df1.iloc[i,1]  and str(m)+str(2)==df1.iloc[(i+1),1]: 
               avg=((df1.iloc[i,5]+df1.iloc[i+1,5])/2)  
               #print(str(m)+str(1),str(m)+str(2))
               name.append(str(m)+str(1))
               name.append(str(m)+str(2))
               df1.iloc[i+1,6]=avg

                #print(avg)
               elif str(m)+str(1)==df1.iloc[i,1]  and str(m)+str(2)!=df1.iloc[(i+1),1]: 
              avrg=(df1.iloc[i,5]  )
                 df1.iloc[i,6]=avrg
               name.append(str(m)+str(1))



    print(len(name),len(key))
    print(set(key)-set(name))
    #print(df1)
```

Comment: link for csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WERalKSw866wwcL97GhoWQ1jBbaj-2F5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The error means that you are passing an index to iloc that does not exist in the dataframe. Try cleaning your code a little bit. Are the for loops necessary? It's difficult to tell what you are trying to do. Maybe there is a better solution.